# CSS transitionend event not detected with ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

I have an angular app in which I use ngAnimate to make the ngHide and ngShow transitions look better.  I am trying to get the transitionend event but it does not seem to register for the ng-hide, ng-hide-remove, or ng-hide-add classes.  The event fired with another class and transition I had.  Does anyone know why the events don't fire for angular classes?

Would appreciate the help!

Comment: Use the [$animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate) service instead, which returns a callback promise.

Comment: Will I be able to get the transitionend event from the $animate service .on(..) hook?  Doesn't ngAnimate only support addClass and removeClass for ngShow and ngHide?

Comment: Decided against using ng-hide for my animations at all after seeing many threads like [these](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/29).  Instead I used [this native animation guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/look-and-feel/animations/animating-between-views?hl=en) from Google.

Comment: Not sure I understand what that thread has to do with using ngAnimate, but I'm glad you solved your issue.  Best of luck.

Comment: My apologies, that must be confusing.  Essentially, there is an unresolved issue with canvas (chart.js uses canvas) and show/hide behavior of ui elements. I tried to workaround it based on the suggestions provided but to no luck.  My current approach works much more nicely.Thanks and good luck in whatever you're working on too!